# $k$th derivative with respect to $y$ of $(x+y)^j y^{n-j}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, combinatorics, partial-derivative

Let $n \ge k \ge j \ge 1$ and $x,y$ are real variable. What is
$$
\frac{\partial^k}{\partial y^k} ((x+y)^j y^{n-j})_{x=1,y=-1}?
$$
It seems it would be $(-1)^{n-k} k! \left( n-j \atop k-j \right)$.

Comment: I am not able to see it immediately. One can expand $(x+y)^j$ and then take k-th derivative with respect to y. But soon the calculation becomes messy.

Answer (score 3):

Observe the following: in order for a term in the final answer to have a nonzero value, each $x+y$ term must be differentiated exactly once (and each $y$ term must be differentiated at most once, so that $k-j$ of the $y$ terms must be differentiated exactly once).

There are $\binom{n-j}{k-j}$ ways of picking which $y$ terms get differentiated, and for each of these, $k!$ orders possible for differentiating the $(x+y)$ and selected $y$ terms. Each of these has $n-j - (k-j)$ leftover undifferentiated $y$ terms, which each contribute $-1$ when evaluated at $y=-1$. Therefore the answer is
$$\binom{n-j}{k-j}k!(-1)^{n-k},$$
as you conjectured.

Comment: I had ideas of similar kind, but I thought it is possible to prove by simply expanding the factors and doing the differentiation. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @user41481 Sure, there must be a way to get an equivalent expression by expanding with the binomial theorem and mucking around with binomial coefficient identities. But why use brute force if there's an easy combinatorial argument?

Answer (score 0):

I guess @user7530 pointed out the right direction, but I was writing this lengthy answer, so I'll write it down here just in case it is helpful:

For simplicity, we use $a, b$ in place of $x+y, y$. Using product rule, we find that the $j$-th derivative with respect to $y$ is
$$j!a^0b^{n-j}+\binom{j}{1}(j\cdots 2)(n-j)a^1b^{n-j-1}+\binom{j}{2}(j\cdots 3)(n-j)(n-j-1)a^2b^{n-j-2}+\cdots+\binom{j}{j-1}j(n-j)\cdots(n-2j+2)a^{j-1}b^{n-2j+1}+(n-j)\cdots(n-2j+1)a^jb^{n-2j}.$$
Now we find $j+1, j+2,\dots$-th derivative. Notice that when evaluated at $x=1,y=-1$, the terms with $a$ disappear. So we try to find a pattern and I will not write down all the terms.

The $j+1$-th derivative:
$$j!(n-j)b^{n-j-1}+\binom{j}{1}(j!)(n-j)b^{n-j-1}+\binom{j}{1}(j\cdots 2)(n-j)(n-j-1)ab^{n-j-2}+\binom{j}{2}(j\cdots 2)(n-j)(n-j-1)a b^{n-j-2}+\binom{j}{2}(j\cdots 3)(n-j)(n-j-1)(n-j-2)b^{n-j-3}+\cdots$$
Notice that the first two terms combine as $(j+1)!(n-j)b^{n-j-1}$, the next one combines as 
$$\binom{j+2}{2}(j\cdots 2)(n-j)(n-j-1)ab^{n-j-2}$$
The latter ones combine as $\binom{j+1}{3}\cdots$, where we use Pascal's identity 
$$\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}=\binom{n}{k}.$$

Now doing the same thing for $j+2$-th derivative, we obtain
$$(j+1)!(n-j)(n-j-1)b^{n-j-2}+\binom{j+1}{2}(j\cdots 2)(n-j)(n-j-1)b^{n-j-2}+\cdots.$$
The first two term combine as
$$\frac{1}{2}(j+2)!(n-j)(n-j-1)b^{n-j-2}.$$
Using Pascal's identity again we see the other terms has $\binom{j+2}{i}$ as coefficients. Repeating this process, we obtain
$$\frac{1}{(k-j)!} k! \frac{(n-j)!}{(n-k)!}(-1)^{n-k}$$
when plugging $0$ into $a$ and $-1$ into $b$.

Comment: But you do not get the desired answer!

Comment: @user41481: I forgot the $(n-j)\cdots$ factor. Now it is the desired form.

Answer (score 0):

> One can expand $(x+y)^j$ and then take $k$-th derivative with respect
>   to $y$. But soon the calculation becomes messy.

Well carrying out this, we have

$$
\frac{\partial^k}{\partial y^k}(1+y)^j y^{n-j} = \frac{\partial^k}{\partial y^k}\sum_{r=0}^j \binom{j}{r}y^{n-j+r} = \sum_{r=0}^j \binom{j}{r}\frac{\partial^k}{\partial y^k}y^{n-j+r}
$$
Now applying the derivative on $y^m$ and rearranging the terms a bit

\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^j \binom{j}{r}\frac{\partial^k}{\partial y^k}y^{n-j+r}&=\sum_{r=k+j-n}^j \binom{j}{r} \frac{(n-j+r)!}{(n-j+r-k)!} y^{n-j+r-k}\\
&=k!y^{n-k}\sum_{r=k+j-n}^j \binom{j}{r} \binom{n-j+r}{k} y^{-j+r}\\
&=k!y^{n-k}\sum_{r=0}^{j} \binom{j}{r} \binom{n-r}{k} y^{-r}
\end{align}
Since we are interested in $y=-1$, we reduced the original conjecture to 
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{j} \binom{j}{r} \binom{n-r}{k} (-1)^{r} = \binom{n-j}{k-j}.
$$
I could'nt find purely algebraic proof of the last proposition, but it has known combinatorial proof, see for example [Use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to show that for any non-negative integers $m, r, n$ such that $m≤r≤n$...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536015/use-the-inclusion-exclusion-principle-to-show-that-for-any-non-negative-integers).